# Fatal Error Detected - How to know what's wrong

Tags: pyinstaller

I've just created my first .exe using pyinstaller. It's a onefile executable. However, when I run it it just throws an error message titled 'Fatal error detected' with the comment 'Failed to execute script myscript"

I tried running the exe from the command prompt in the hopes of it showing me what was causing this error, but nothing.

How do you diagnose what the error is? I can't seem to find any information as to why it won't run, and the error message is completely uninformative. I have no idea what needs to be changed/fixed in order for my .exe to run.

Any help much appreciated!

Edit:
I've just found this on the pyinstaller website (https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html): "If you are using the --windowed option, your bundled application ay fail to start with an error message like Failed to execute script my_gui."
This is the error message I'm getting. However I am not using windowed mode. All I'm typing to create my .exe is $ pyinstaller -F myscript.py
It does use tkinter. Can that be the problem?

Comment: say `pyinstaller -F -c myscript.py` and a console might open up, and the error will pop on the console, then post that error code here

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it turns out pyinstaller would have spat the error message out if I weren't trying to be too clever. I'd already changed my .py script into .pyw to silence the command window. I changed it back to .py and reran pyinstaller. When I ran it, it opened a command window and spat an error out!

And the error was that it couldn't find the icon (.ico) file I wanted to use for the tkinter window that would open.

So I guess, when first running a script in pyinstaller, make sure it's a .py to check for errors before you turn it into a .pyw

Comment: Always make sure to copy the exe to the project directory